# How to write data to JSON file with socket.io and node.js?

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, socket.io

I want to get data from the user and write it to my json file with the following code:

```
var fs = require('fs');


module.exports = function (io) {
    io.on('connection', function (socket) {
        socket.on("search list", function(search_data){

            // write my object to JSON document
            let data = JSON.stringify(search_data); // {"name": "John", "age": "25"}             

            fs.writeFile('./list.json', data, (err) => {  
                if (err) throw err;
                console.log('Data written to file');
            });

        });
    });
};
```

I have a message in my console: "Data written to file". But my `./list.json` still empty. Why? 
My `websocket.js` file and `list.json` are placed in the same folder.

Comment: what do you get when you `console.log()` the data

Comment: Try passing some static data as `data`

Comment: @turmuka clear json {"name": "John", "age": "25"}, etc

Comment: @Rayon tried: {"data":"asd"}. Isn't working...

Comment: try `JSON.stringify({"data":"asd"})` , and your program runs fine on my cpu

Comment: Run *node inspect yourfile.js* and check your code line by line ( enter *next*)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was with a path.

```
        fs.writeFile(__dirname +'/list.json', data, (err) => {  
            if (err) throw err;
            console.log('Data written to file');
        });
```